# Oracle Cloud Custom image installation

Tags: oracle, cloud

does anyone aware of below

1. can we install windows (windows 10) instance on Oracle cloud with a iso image ?
2. if so can it be done on always free category ?

Mangala.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "no" to both. You can import custom VM images such as VMDK, QCOW2, KVM or OVM, and you can customize hosts created from OCI published OS images, but you cannot install from your own ISO. Also, custom images are not available to the free tier.